# go struct with generics implementing comparable

Tags: go, generics

Consider the following code snippet for version go1.18beta2 linux/amd64

```go
    type Vector[T comparable] struct {
       data_ []T
    }
    
    func (v *Vector[T]) Contains(e T) bool {
       for _, x := range v.data_ {
          if x == e {
             return true
          }
       }
       return false
    }
    
    func TestVector(t *testing.T) {
       v2 := Vector[Vector[int]]{}
    }
```

This does not compile and gives error: `“Vector[int] does not implement comparable”` simply because `Vector` has no equality operators defined. However, I cannot find how to define them.

**Question**: Is this approach of creating a comparable struct not allowed, and why; or is the documentation not written yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constraint `comparable` is predeclared and supported by the language specifications. You can't "manually" make a type implement it. The documentation is available in the specs (under [Type Constraints](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_constraints)):

> The predeclared interface type comparable denotes the set of all concrete (non-interface) types that are [comparable](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators). Specifically, a type T implements comparable if:
>
> - `T` is not an interface type and `T` supports the operations == and !=; or
> - `T` is an interface type and each type in `T`'s type set implements comparable.

Your type `Vector[T comparable]` doesn't meet any of those conditions. It is not an interface type, and it does not otherwise support the equality operations, because one of its fields `data_ []T` is not comparable due to being a slice — even if element type is constrained by `comparable`.

The purpose of the `comparable` constraint is really just to allow writing generic code with `==` and `!=` operators. If a type is not comparable by design, you can't write such code. That would be true even if `Vector` didn't have a type parameter.

If your goal is instantiating `Vector[Vector[T]]` and allow equality tests between instances of `Vector[T]`, you might want to add an `Equal` method that takes care of this specific use case — only vectors instantiated with the same type parameter as the receiver will be allowed:

```
func (v *Vector[T]) Equal(e Vector[T]) bool {
    // test equality in a way that makes sense for this type
}
```

---

Worth mentioning that there is a way to make `Vector[T comparable]` comparable itself, i.e. change the `data_` field to be a pointer-to-slice:

```
type Vector[T comparable] struct {
    data_ *[]T
}
```

Now instantiation with `Vector[Vector[int]]` compiles. However, beside being very cumbersome to initialize with struct literals ([playground](https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/zSx2mjLmptz)), it comes with all caveats of pointer comparison. More specifically:

> Two pointer values are equal if they point to the same variable or if both have value nil. Pointers to distinct zero-size variables may or may not be equal.

Now the comparison `x == e` tests that the memory address stored in the `data_` field in `x` and `e` is the same. This might skew the semantics of comparing two `Vector[T]` instances — is it correct to say that two vector instances are equal if they hold a reference to the same slice? Maybe. It depends on the assumptions your program wants to make. Personally, I don't think this is actually better than having a separate `Equal` method and/or redesigning your data types, but as usual, YMMV.

Note also that if you instantiate as `Vector[float64]` and compare `NaN` values, the comparison will be false.

Comment: Thank you, this answer makes prefect sense. But this leaves me with an uneasy feeling that these first experiments with go generics stalls here…

Comment: This example illustrates my main motivation to use generics. And I'm trying to cope with the slight disappointment. Or is there another method to create comparable structs (that are resizable such as slices)?

Comment: @HJLebbink right now I’m not aware of a cleaner design. One might be tempted to use `comparable` in unions or type assertions, but that’s not possible.. If a type is not comparable by design, it has to be handled differently, e.g. by implementing Equal methods etc… Note that arrays are comparable~ but have fixed length

Comment: @HJLebbink you can make `Vector[T]` comparable by declaring the field as a pointer, like `data_ *[]T`. Pointers as per the specs quoted above are comparable. However I'm not sure it's preferable because 1) initialization and usage become more cumbersome and verbose, 2) pointer comparison tests whether the mem address is the same, so `x == e` where `T` is another `Vector[T]` instance basically checks if the two structs hold the same exact slice pointer. YMMV. Example https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/zSx2mjLmptz

Comment: @blackgreen Might be worth mentioning the usual `NaN` caveats: https://go.dev/play/p/SlZCtn6PEUe

Comment: @jub0bs thanks for the heads-up, surely it doesn't hurt to mention that; though the OP's use case in this particular Q&A was to instantiate Vector with another Vector so that `x == e` would compare two `Vector[T]`. The OP initially failed because the struct has a slice field, hence the admittedly bad trick to change the field to a slice pointer.